# Connecting more than one Client to server: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, sockets, server, indexoutofboundsexception

I hope you can help me with my problem.

I have a ServerClass and a ClientClass, and I am able to connect these two Programms. But if I want to conncect more than one Client to my Server over the same Virtutal Machine I receive following error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

I passed my programm a command line argument!

But I don't know why... Here is the part which is important for my problem:

```
public class ClientStart {
[...]

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Geben Sie Ihre IP-Adresse ein: ");
        ipadress = readString();
        args[0] = ipadress;
        System.out.println("");
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        connect();
        ipadress = "";
    }

    public static void connect() {
        InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress
                = new InetSocketAddress(ipadress, 56789);
[...]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your server side code? (part of code that accepts client connection)

Comment: If you provide a minimum runnable code, it would be great to help you.

Comment: Can you post how did you write the command line?

Comment: Under Project Properties in Netbeans I passed the argument "x"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The args[] in the main method is for arguments passed when the program is executed. You cannot use args[0] because the program is called without parameters and the array is empty.

Just use the value you read in ipadress and don't try to assign it to args[0]. I could be more helpful if you had given more code.

```
args[0] = ipadress; // Args here is an empty array - you don't need that line
```

Comment: I passed my programm a command line argument... So Args is no empty array?

Comment: How do you call the program? You cannot change args I think. just dont use it. You don't need it :)

Comment: ServerClass has its own Main-Method and ClientClass has another one

Comment: well I told you the problem. Without more code it will be hard to see what is wrong. You don't need to modify args though. You use ipaddress field

Answer (score 1):

`args` is an array whose length is determined (like any other array) during initialization.

In your case, probably since you don't pass any arguments to your program, its' size is zero and therefore

```
args[0] = ipadress;
```

throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` since the array is of length zero.

Comment: But the OP question said he passed an argument in command line therefore args is not empty anymore.